# dynamic name for a file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dynamic, filenames

I have a subject_id which is a dynamic number.For instance, it could be equal to 60. I am manually defining some file names as follows:
x_file = "50.txt"
x_csv_file = "50.csv"
The number (50) could have been 1 or any-number else. Is there any way that I can define `subject_id=50` JUST one time and then use those names as `x_file = "subject_id.txt"` and `x_csv_file = "subject_id.csv"`?. 
Thanks For your help

Comment: You'll probably want to save `subject_id='50'` and then do `x_file=subject_id + '.txt'` and `x_csv_file=subject_id + '.csv:` The `+` between two strings acts as the concatenation operator, hence the strings are pasted together to produce your desired output

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it gives me the following error:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str

Comment: You're probably missing the quotes around the number then

Comment: @LukasThaler Thanks Lukas. You are right! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to define a simple function for this

```
def file_name(subject_id):
    x_file = '{}.txt'.format(subject_id)
    x_csv_file = '{}.csv'.format(subject_id)
    return x_file, x_csv_file
```

Comment: Worked as a charm!

Comment: You can do `x_csv_file = str(subject_id) + '.csv'` with Lukas' solution too : )

Comment: Why not use f-strings?